# jQuery FlipClock.js - can't change the styling of the clock

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm using `FlipClock.js`.

```js
var clock = $('.your-clock').FlipClock(3000, {
            //clockFace: 'MinuteCounter'
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://run.plnkr.co/preview/ckjarkyfe0006396h66xdt3hl/flipclock.js"></script>
<link href="https://run.plnkr.co/preview/ckjarkyfe0006396h66xdt3hl/flipclock.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="your-clock"></div>
```

My question: is it possible to make the clock to be standard view? Example: 00:54:10 <-- without any styling there.

I tried to modify the code, but there is no luck. :(

Comment: what do you mean by "without any styling" ? you mean just display the text ?

Comment: Hi @KenLee, Yes only display the text

Comment: I see. Please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

For a text-based timer. you may use the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<script>

function TimeStart(initialtime){


var milliseconds = 0; 
var startDate = new Date();   
var time = startDate.getTime(); 
var newTime = time + (1000*3000) ;
var newTime = time ;

var countDownDate = newTime;


var x = setInterval(function() {

var now = new Date().getTime();


var distance =  (now +initialtime*1000 - countDownDate) ;



    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    
    hours=("0"+hours).slice(-2);
    minutes=("0"+minutes).slice(-2);
    seconds=("0"+seconds).slice(-2);
    
    document.getElementById("timedisplay").innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "";
    

}, 500);
}
</script>

<html>
<body>

<div id="timedisplay"></div>



</body>
</html>

<!--Use the following if you want to start only on a button click-->

<button onclick="TimeStart(3000)">Start Timer</button>


<script>
//un-remark the following if you want to auto-start
//TimeStart(3000);
</script>
```

The initialtime is the initial seconds to start.

Comment: Hi, is it use FlipClock plugin?

Comment: Flipclock is a graphical clock. As you need to have a text-based clock (remove all styling), we do not need flipclock and can use javascript

Comment: But, is it possible to use that plugin with text-based clock?